# Is Swift’s filter method stable?

Tags: arrays, swift

When I filter an array in Swift, can I expect the results to be in the same order as the original? For example, can I count on:

```
[3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 7].filter{$0 > 4}
```

always returning:

```
[5, 9, 7]
```

?

Comment: Yes. It will return the same.

Comment: Let's assume it is not. What else would you expect to be returned by `$0 > 4`?

Comment: @LeoNatan, it could return `[9, 5, 7]`. I asked the question because my code needs it to always return `[5, 9, 7]` and I don’t know whether to write checks for that.

Comment: @user3770280 If you feel that this is not adequately clarified by the documentation, you should file a bug report with Apple. I'm sure they'd like to be clear about this sort of thing!

Comment: In the OP's defense, the docs are silent about this. The example given **implies** that the results are in the same order as the source array, but don't sate that explicitly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can count on it. The `filter` instance method of Array calls the global `filter` method, whose comment in the Swift header file explicitly says:

> Return an `Array` containing the elements of `source`, *in order*, that satisfy the predicate

(my italics).

Moreover, the whole point of these methods on Array such as `map` and `filter` (and, for that matter, `reduce`) is that an array is *ordered* and they cycle through the array *in that order*. An Array is a *sequence* (a SequenceType): it has a generator with a `next()` method that is called repeatedly in order to cycle through the array *in order*, and this `next()` method *is* how such methods *do* cycle through the array.

Comment: Note, however, that the sort method is *not* guaranteed to maintain the relative order of elements for which areInIncreasingOrder does not establish an order.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not explicitly mentioned, it appears that that is the case according to the [examples in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html)

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
let filteredArray = array.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
// filteredArray is [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Array manipulation methods tend to maintain order across the board whenever it makes sense, and it does here. I would be very surprised if it did *not* come back in the same order. But once again since it is not explicitly mentioned, it may be a good idea to write a check in the form of an assert in case they change it down the line.

Comment: Actually, it is explicitly mentioned, as [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) writes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29440393/242933). See [Apple's documentation for the `filter(_:)` instance method of the `Sequence` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter), to which `Array` conforms.